# Identity Migration Changes AspNetUserTokens & AspNetUserLogins For No Reason

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have scaffolded a solution using Entity Framework 3.1.  The first migration proceeds without problems.  The second migration mysteriously changes the with of columns in AspNetUserTokens and AspNetUserLogins tables for no reason.  I am adding tables in the migration that have nothing to do with these tables.

The code in the migration files is as follows:

```
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "Name",
        table: "AspNetUserTokens",
        maxLength: 128,
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "LoginProvider",
        table: "AspNetUserTokens",
        maxLength: 128,
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "ProviderKey",
        table: "AspNetUserLogins",
        maxLength: 128,
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "LoginProvider",
        table: "AspNetUserLogins",
        maxLength: 128,
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
```

The Update-Database command in the Package Manager Console fails because the column widths have changed in an inconsistent way.  Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here and how to fix it?

This is a real show stopper.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just hit the same problem. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I got this problem too.

Comment: No.  I opened a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: @user3802434 can you provide the link for the support case?

Comment: MS support gave this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-primary-key-type. They specifically referenced item 4.  I haven't been able to explore it adequately.

Comment: Had this problem too. Could not find the source of it (I had changed some things in middleware to take out Identity Session stuff so I could use JWTs instead, so tried reverting to see if any of these had done this). Nothing seems to trigger this except adding a second migration. I commented out these changes from the second migration (both up and down) and subsequent migrations seem to be fine (EF is not re-adding these changes even though they have not taken effect on the DB with an update). Point 4 from the MS docs website doesn't seem to help either (at least not straightforwardly).

Comment: One more victim here! Any possible cause anyone found out yet?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this question, I had this when adding custom a identity user type. You can set the `MaxLengthForKeys` when registering Identity in `Startup.cs`, for example:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If you then revert the db context model snapshot cs file and then rescaffold the migration, the resulting migration shouldn't then change those column lengths - assuming the default previously was 128 of course.

Comment: THIS MAY NOT WORK! See [this github bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7568).

Comment: does not work for me. in ASP.NET CORE 7, "options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys" seems to have no effect.